# What is Flask route?

Tags: python, flask

I am looking at example

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

As an explanation,[quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)
says that we use the route() decorator to tell Flask what URL should trigger our function.In Grinberg's book route is defined as an association between a URL and the function that handles it.
URL referrs to webserver or client?
I do not understand how it is related to URL syntax

```
scheme://host:port/path?query-string#fragment-id
```

Comment: How would a URL refer to the client or the webserver? What you are really interested in is the *path component* of the URL. This question has a URL, starting with `https://stackoverflow.com`. Note the rest, the part that starts with `/questions/...`, that's the *path component*. Flask routes register a *path pattern* to match. `@app.route('/questions/<int:question_id>/<title>')` would match the path of this question and any others.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks.I am new to Flask.But what about Tornado,does it work in the same manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running Flask means, basically, that you are running a webserver, also known as an HTTP server.

The Flask server will respond if a request is made for the URL defined in the route. This happens either when you visit the URL in your browser, or when some other HTTP client tries to access that URL.

The argument to `app.route()` is the *path* component of the URL. If you run a Flask server, the hostname of the machine it runs on will be the *host* component. The port it listens on will be the *port*. The *scheme* will be `http`. So if you ran the above example on a machine located at 52.12.34.56, listening on port 8088, you could reach the endpoint by going to `http://52.12.34.56:8088/`. You could also add a query-string or a fragment-id - the latter would be ignored, the former would be seen by the Flask server. So you could change the Python code in the function `hello_world` so that it returns different output depending on the query-string.

If you were using Flask in a formal production setting, you could have other servers doing things like proxying or load balancing involved in your setup. So potentially your users might visit a URL with a hostname which points to your load balancer, and that would pass on the request to Flask, possibly changing the URL in various ways. At the moment, you shouldn't worry about that. Just try and see if you can run a server and load the right page to see the text 'Hello World!' in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
route(rule, **option)
```

A route is a decorator that is used to register a view function for a given URL rule.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

**rule** – the URL rule as string
**options** – the options to be forwarded to the underlying Rule object. A change to Werkzeug is handling of method options. methods is a list of methods this rule should be limited to (GET, POST etc.). By default a rule just listens for GET (and implicitly HEAD). Starting with Flask 0.6, OPTIONS is implicitly added and handled by the standard request handling.